# Create JSON from website

Tags: python, json

I am trying to scrape a website, and convert its contents to JSON. I have been able to write the code to scrape it and all of its subcategories, but I can't figure out how to generate a nice JSON File, using the following structure

```
Category[1]: "Name of category"
    Article[1]
        Title: "Some title"
        Text: "Some Text"
        Image: "Some image"
    Article[2]
        ...
        ...
        ...
    ...
Category[2]: "Name of category"
    Article[1]
        Title: "Some title"
        Text: "Some Text"
        Image: "Some image"
    Article[2]
        ...
        ...
        ...
    ...
```

I am a newbie in python, so any explanation is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since the output you showed isn't anything close to valid JSON, I'm not sure exactly what output you want. But the answer is the same:

Never worry about "creating a JSON file". Just create a dict full of dicts and lists, then call [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) to turn that dict into a JSON file.

For example, maybe something like this:

```
categories = {}
for thing in thingies:
    name = get_next_category_name()
    articles = get_articles(name)
    categories[name] = [convert_article(article) for article in articles]
with open(path, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(categories, f)
```